# Restart JDBC Resource in GlassFish / EclipseLink

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

Sometimes I run into a situation that requires to "restart" the `PersistenceContext`, but the only way I find is to restart the GlassFish' domain, thing that I would like to avoid.

For instance, today I was unable to deploy an application because an `Enumerated` property had a value in the db that was not present in the enum values, and JPA was giving the error:

```
no conversion value provided for the value [foo] in field [bar]
```

I decided to redefine the field in the db `schema`. But after this change, I could not find a way to make `GlassFish` / `EclipseLink` aware of the change.

Is there a JDBC-resource-restart option that avoids restarting the domain?

Answer (score 0):

You could redeploy the application. (you would need to change the code anyway, would you not?)

If using an application managed persistence unit ensure you close your EntityManagerFactory when undeploying.

Comment: In the particular case of my question, the project was not deployed because the JPA exception was thrown during an EJB instantiation at startup. And I use container managed persistence, with injection of the PersistenceContext. So, I don't have access to the EntityManagerFactory directly.